# Completeness of formal power series rings over various linearly topologized commutative rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and fix an ideal $I\subseteq R$, such that $R$ is complete with respect to the $I$-adic topology. When is a formal power series ring $R[[X_{1},\dots,X_{d}]]$ over $R$ complete with respect to the
$IR[[X_{1},\dots,X_{d}]]$-adic topology?